# How much overtension can I put on a guitar string before it snaps?

Tags: strings

In relation to this question

[Which strings do I need to play these notes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/which-strings-do-i-need-to-play-these-notes)

I have calculated that I will have to take the highest string upto 150% of the maximum stated Newtons (I have tried calculating D-addario pl007 to pl0095, they all need 150% overtension), and the next string needs 135% overtension.

(All the other strings are around 100% of maximum tension.)

Will this automatically break the strings, or can I buy the strings and see what happens?

Is there an alternative type of string that might handle higher Newtons per linear-mass?

Thank you.

Clarification: it isn't a guitar.  It looks ugly but it works.

[image: harp prototype]

Comment: Just asking to break not only strings but the instrument as well!  Why not search out the equivalent of a "soprano guitar" designed to produce the frequency range of interest?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: You mean, a Ukulele?

Comment: @David  ;-)  Tiny Tim returns!

Comment: Hmmmm - with your picture edited in, I guess this is a home made instrument? If so, you'll probably be the one to decide whether it can cope with the tension!

Comment: It's quite strong enough, I just don't want to waste money on strings when I should redesign the sides instead.  I will recalculate string tensions to see what the new measurements will be.

Comment: Wow! That top beam where the machine heads are looks really thin, and is at right angles to the string tension. I'd be quite worried about that snapping. Also, the more flexible the frame, the more it will dissipate the energy of the strings and damp them. Good luck with your project! PS I would probably call that a harp. Have you ever seen a zither? it's another way to go with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Carl said, you may need to rethink your plan. The strings **may** cope with that much overtension.

The neck of the guitar is quite likely to be catastrophically damaged! Bent, or possibly snapped.

Just use an instrument designed for the higher range, or possibly play much higher up the neck - this may sound sarcastic, but people do make 36 fret guitars, such as the [R36 Turbulence from Gary Kramer guitars](http://www.garykramerguitar.com/R36Turbulence.html):

[image]

Comment: Not sure how well this translates to an electric guitar, but that far up the fingerboard (and past it) on an acoustic cello, I can get the notes to sound just by touching the string (as you'd normally do to get the harmonic).

Comment: Yep - natural harmonics work the same with guitar. And they can give a lovely tonal chime.

Comment: I think I will recalculate and see if I can make the strings shorter.

Comment: @DrMayhem a guitar neck is much strong than many realise, see  my answer here for a basic calculation showing a neck is over 18 times stronger than required:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94222/if-a-material-is-built-to-handle-tension-would-removing-the-tension-damage-it/94276#94276

Comment: @Fergus also, it's possible to get well over a semitone of pitch bend on a guitar without a tremolo by pushing or pulling on the neck. I saw Adam Bomb doing this in a small venue near where I live. I spoke to him about it and he said it doesn't harm the guitar. I had a little go on mine and it works, but I really don't want to make a habit of it on my precious instrument.

Comment: Fergus - maybe you'll trust that. I've seen both ends: I have dropped a guitar down a flight of stairs, landing on the headstock and had no damage or loss of tuning, and I have seen a catastrophically broken neck from one set of very heavy strings overtightened. I wouldn't trust that 18x to be consistent across instruments.

Comment: @DrMayhem Of course it is not consistent across instruments as not all instruments dimensions, materials and tensions etc are equal. eg if you double the tension the safety factor becomes 9, still large by any standard, the safety factor for aircraft can be less than 2...We do however, all 'trust that' methodology every day. It is the same method used to build the buildings you enter, the bridges you cross and the cars you drive. It's validity is long past being debatable. Your sample of one in a population of millions means nothing, there is a multitude of other reasons that the guitar broke.